# I wish to show route of 'n' number of drivers (single route for each driver)on Gmap. Its a case of dynamic drivers

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, c#-4.0

Currently i am able to display 3 route of 3 drivers respectively(one for each) on a single Gmap.
Now, I wish to show route of 'n' number of drivers (single route for each driver)on Gmap. Its a case of dynamic drivers. I can get data from db for 'n' number of drivers that i need to display on a single map.

My Code is below for single driver please help me for dynamic craetion of routes:

```
                 var lat_lng1 = [];
                var latlngbounds1 = "";                    
                lat_lng1 = new Array();
                var value1 = markers1.length;

                //Intialize the Path Array
                var path1 = new google.maps.MVCArray();
                //Intialize the Direction Service
                var service1 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var lineSymbol1 = { path1: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE };
                //Set the Path Stroke Color

                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
                    var data1 = markers1[i]
                    var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(data1.lat, data1.lng);
                    lat_lng1.push(myLatlng1);

                    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng1,map: map,icon: icon1});
                    (function (marker1, data1) {
                        // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function (e) {
                            if (i == 0){
                                infoWindow.setContent(data1.Person);infoWindow.open(map, marker1);}
                            if(i=(markers2.length -1)){
                                infoWindow.setContent(data1.Person);infoWindow.open(map, marker1);}
                            else{
                                infoWindow.setContent(data1.Title);
                                infoWindow.open(map, marker1);}
                        });
                    })(marker1, data1);
                }



                poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    // path: lineCoordinates,
                    strokeColor: '#BC456F',
                    icons: [{
                        icon: {
                            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,strokeColor: '#009900',fillColor: '#009900',fillOpacity: 1},
                        repeat: '100px',
                        path1: []
                    }],
                    map: map
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I solved this issue the very next day by calling ajax loops by driver id